`schemachange`, snowflake and oauth authentication in GitHub action
I have been trying to use Oauth Authentication of schemachange in my github action pipeline; however, I get the following error message
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/opt/actions-runner/_work/_tool/Python/3.8.18/x64/bin/schemachange", line 8, in <module>
Using Snowflake account ***
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/actions-runner/_work/_tool/Python/3.8.18/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/schemachange/cli.py", line 1309, in main
    deploy_command(config)
  File "/opt/actions-runner/_work/_tool/Python/3.8.18/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/schemachange/cli.py", line 601, in deploy_command
    session = SnowflakeSchemachangeSession(config)
  File "/opt/actions-runner/_work/_tool/Python/3.8.18/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/schemachange/cli.py", line 283, in __init__
    if self.set_connection_args():
  File "/opt/actions-runner/_work/_tool/Python/3.8.18/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/schemachange/cli.py", line 372, in set_connection_args
    oauth_token = self.get_oauth_token()
  File "/opt/actions-runner/_work/_tool/Python/3.8.18/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/schemachange/cli.py", line 329, in get_oauth_token
    "url": self.oauth_config["token-provider-url"],
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

one might suspect that this is due to improper config on env variable in workflow, for that I have written a python script to get the token and authenticate with snowflake in the same pipeline, and it works. This is the Github pipleine:
name: testing

on:
    push:
        branches:
            - feat/*

jobs:
    
    Deploy:    
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest

        permissions:
            id-token: write
            contents: read

        defaults:
            run:
                shell: bash

        environment: 
            name: 'Dev-WB' 
        
        # get environment variables from the environment
        env:
            SF_ACCOUNT: ${{ secrets.SF_ACCOUNT }}
            SF_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.SF_USERNAME }}
            SF_ROLE: ${{ secrets.SF_ROLE_MULESOFT }}
            SF_ROLE_TASK: ${{ secrets.SF_ROLE_TASK }}
            SF_WAREHOUSE: ${{ vars.SF_WAREHOUSE_MULESOFT }}
            SF_DATABASE: ${{ vars.SF_DATABASE }}
            SCHEMA_AI_MODEL: ${{ vars.SCHEMA_AI_MODEL }}
            SCHEMA_FEATURE_STORE: ${{ vars.SCHEMA_FEATURE_STORE }}
            SCHEMA_REPORT: ${{ vars.SCHEMA_REPORT }}
            AZURE_ORG_GUID: ${{ vars.AZURE_ORG_GUID }}
            CLIENT_ID: ${{ vars.CLIENT_ID }}
            CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ vars.CLIENT_SECRET }}
            SCOPE_URL_TEST: ${{ vars.SCOPE_URL_TEST }}
            SNOWFLAKE_AUTHENTICATOR: oauth

        steps:
            - name: Checkout repository
              uses: actions/checkout@v4
      
            - name: Use Python 3.8.x
              uses: actions/setup-python@v5
              with:
                python-version: 3.8.x
            
            - name: Install Python dependencies
              run: |
                pip install --upgrade pip
                pip install -r code/python/requirements.txt
            
            - name: Run python
              run: |
                python code/python/src/snowflake_conn_tocken.py


            - name: Run schemachange to deploy the snowflake Stored Procedures
              run: |

                schemachange -f ${{ github.workspace }}/code/schemachange/stored_procedure  \
                -a $SF_ACCOUNT \
                -r $SF_ROLE \
                -u $SF_USERNAME \
                -w $SF_WAREHOUSE \
                -d $SF_DATABASE \
                -c $SF_DATABASE.MRVWORK_DNA_DISCOVER.CLAIM_SCHEMACHANGE_CHANGE_HISTORY --create-change-history-table \
                --vars '{"schema_ai_model": "${{vars.SCHEMA_AI_MODEL}}", "schema_feature_store": "${{vars.SCHEMA_FEATURE_STORE}}", "schema_report": "${{vars.SCHEMA_REPORT}}"}'  # schema's names change based on the environment
                --oauth-config '{"url": ${{ vars.AZURE_ORG_GUID }}, "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "User-Agent": "python/schemachange"}, "data": {"client_id": CLIENT_ID: ${{ vars.CLIENT_ID }}, "client_secret": ${{ vars.CLIENT_SECRET }}, "grant_type": 'client_credentials', "scope": ${{ vars.SCOPE_URL_TEST }}}'
                

I'm guessing the problem is that schemachange can't parse/access the env? Anyone can help me with this?

https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/schemachange/issues/283#issuecomment-2389496912
